# How to apply a function that receives two parameters as columns with pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

In pandas I know that a function can be applied as follows:

```
 df.apply(f, axis=1)
```

However, I have a function that receives two parameters, for example let's say:

```
def a_sum(x,y):
    return x+y
```

How can I apply the above function by taking as parameters the elements of `ColA` and `ColB`:

```
ColA ColB ColC ColD
1    2    True False
1    1    True False
1    4    True False
...
1    10    True False
```

In order to produce this new column `ColF`:

```
ColA ColB ColC ColD   ColF
1    2    True False   3
1    1    True False   2
1    4    True False   5
...
1    10    True False  11
```

Comment: Is this a representative example? Because there are faster ways of summing 2 columns.

Comment: yes it's actually the same... the issue is that a column is a string, but pandas seems to put it as a float although I cast it into an int

Comment: Is this what you want? `df.iloc[:, :2].astype(int).sum(axis=1)`

Comment: it's more like @piRSquared answer..

Comment: Isn't that what you want? :p

Comment: Edit your post with data that includes problematic rows or even better, post a new question on how to handle bad data.

Comment: @piRSquared Thanks for the help and for your time!... I handle the value error with a try except statament. As you told me there were some `NaN` values inside the data... I did not see them since it's a large dataframe!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from itertools import starmap

df.assign(F=list(starmap(a_sum, df[['ColA', 'ColB']].values)))

   ColA  ColB  ColC   ColD   F
0     1     2  True  False   3
1     1     1  True  False   2
2     1     4  True  False   5
3     1    10  True  False  11
```

---

**Timing**
With Large Data

```
df = pd.concat([df] * 1000, ignore_index=True)

%timeit df.assign(F=list(starmap(a_sum, df[['ColA', 'ColB']].values)))
%timeit df.assign(F=df.apply(lambda row: a_sum(row.ColA, row.ColB), axis=1))

100 loops, best of 3: 5.01 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 90.7 ms per loop
```

Comment: which is more efficient?

Comment: Over small data, the same.  Over large data... `starmap`

Comment: Althought this works I got: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'`... any idea of how to fix it?

Comment: One of your columns is an int and the other is a str

Comment: Yes, I tried to cast it using `int()`. However, I got: `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 17087,17098`

Comment: That's bad data you need to clean up.  You can use `pd.to_numeric(df['BadColumn'], errors='coerce')`

Comment: Again got a value error :O : `ValueError: Unable to parse string "17087, 17098 at position 149`

Answer (score 2):

When use `apply` method with `axis=1`, you pass a row which is also a Series to the function, to apply custom `f` here, you can wrap it with a lambda function that takes the row and then pass `ColA` and `ColB` as parameters to `f`.

```
df.apply(lambda row: f(row.ColA, row.ColB), axis=1)
```

---

```
df['ColE'] = df.apply(lambda row: a_sum(row.ColA, row.ColB), axis=1)
df
#ColA   ColB    ColC    ColD    ColE
#0  1      2    True    False   3
#1  1      1    True    False   2
#2  1      4    True    False   5
#3  1     10    True    False   11
```

Comment: Althought this works I got: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'`... any idea of how to fix it?

Comment: Check the data type of ColA and ColB. Make sure they are what you expected. `df[['ColA', 'ColB']].dtypes`.

Comment: Yes, I tried to cast it using `int()`. However, I got: `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 17087,17098`

Comment: Try `df.ColA.astype(int)` and `df.ColB.astype(int)`. But it's possible you have str column that can't be converted to ints, for instance if it has entry like `17087,17098`.

Answer (score 2):

```
df['ColF'] =  df.apply(lambda x: a_sum(x['ColA'], x['ColB']), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Could also use

```
df['ColF'] = [a+b for a,b in zip(df['ColA'],df['ColB'])]
```

or if your true function is more custom

```
df['ColF'] = [a_sum(a,b) for a,b in zip(df['ColA'],df['ColB'])]
```